# Filter posts by category

Tags: wp-query, categories

How can I get posts from a specific category on a custom category page?

The below code gets the posts from all categories but I can't find a way to filter according to a specific category.  Can someone point me in the right direction to filter by a specific category.

```
<?php // Display blog posts on any page @ http://m0n.co/l
        $temp = $wp_query; $wp_query= null;
        $wp_query = new WP_Query(); $wp_query->query('showposts=2' . '&paged='.$paged);
        while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post(); ?>

        <div class="col-md-6 col-post-blog wow fadeInUp">

        <div class="post-blog">

        <?php the_post_thumbnail('large'); ?>

        <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="Read more"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
        <?php the_excerpt(); ?>

        <p><span class="fa fa-clock-o"></span> <?php the_time('F j, Y') ?></p>
         </div><!--col-md-6-->
         </div><!--post-blog-->

        <?php endwhile; ?>

        <?php if ($paged > 1) { ?>

        <ul class="pagination pagination-lg">

            <li><?php next_posts_link('&laquo; Previous Posts'); ?></li>
            <li><?php previous_posts_link('Newer Posts &raquo;'); ?></li>
        </ul>

        <?php } else { ?>

        <ul class="pagination pagination-lg">

            <li><?php next_posts_link('&laquo; Previous Posts'); ?></li>
            <li class="disabled"><a>Newer Posts &raquo;</a></li>
        </ul>

        <?php } ?>

        <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

Comment: Did you check the [doc](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Category_Parameters) ?

Comment: you already have the custom category template? that in itself should show the posts of the category. what is the result if you do not add the custom query parameters?

Answer (score -1):

As per the [WP Query Codex page](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Category_Parameters) all you need to do is change your wp query to this:

```
$wp_query = new WP_Query( array( 'cat' => $cat_id ) );
```